# Composer2 v2.4.3 : Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, sigkill

I'm using DataprocSubmitJobOperator in GCP Composer2(Airflow dags) and the jobs are failing in Composer v2.4.3, while the jobs are going through in the v2.2.5 clusters.

Error is as shown below:

```
[2023-05-05, 19:10:59 PDT] {dataproc.py:1953} INFO - Submitting job
[2023-05-05, 19:10:59 PDT] {base.py:71} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2023-05-05, 19:10:59 PDT] {credentials_provider.py:323} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2023-05-05, 19:11:02 PDT] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
```

Both the clusters are small clusters, and have similar configurations (pls see screenshot attached)

Any ideas on how to fix this on v2.4.3 ?

[image: v2.2.5]

[image: v2.4.3]

Answer (score 1):

Your Airflow workers might be running out of memory. You can try increasing it and see if it solves the issue. For more information see [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#task-fails-with-negsignalsigkill).